# Artifactory maven 3 unable to find a snapshot file

Tags: maven, artifactory, maven-metadata

I am having problems getting artifactory to suppy a jar file to a maven 3 build process

I have deploy the jar file  gwt-openlayers-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to  libs-snapshot-local

I can find this jar file by using the general lookup in the Artifacts tab, it shows up as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-openlayers-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-20130320.151820-1</version>
</dependency>
```

So I known artifactory has it.

When I attempt to do a build using a pom with the following section in it

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-openlayers-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I get a build error with a diagnostic about being unable to find gwt-openlater-server, see listing.

I don't understand why I am having this problem,  artifactory has the file!

I am using mvn -U  compile

Any suggestions

Comment: from which repository in Artifactory are you trying to resolve? is it directly from libs-snapshot-local or a virtual repository aggregating it?

Comment: Tried taking it from libs-snapshot and libs-snapshot-local

Comment: Tried taking it from libs-snapshot and libs-snapshot-local by editing the /etc/maven/settings.xml in the quote example it was trying to get it from libs-snapshot.  If I try and http access, its shows the jar files are listed as being there.  As far as I make out the jar files are listed with a version set to something like 1.0 timestamp

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-openlayers-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-20130320.151820-1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: In your settings.xml, did you configure libs-snapshot as a snapshots repository? it looks like it is being treated as a release repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have maven-metadata.xml corruption, or perhaps your snapshot info is empty. It shouldn't be.